# Creating KeyEvent with specific fields

Tags: java, swing, key-events

How would I go about changing the fields of a generated KeyEvent?

Actual KeyEvent from keyboard

```
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,
keyCode=65,
keyText=A,
keyChar='a',
keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,
rawCode=65,
primaryLevelUnicode=97,
scancode=30,
extendedKeyCode=0x41] on panel0
```

Generated KeyEvent

```
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,
keyCode=65,
keyText=A,
keyChar='a',
keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,
rawCode=0,
primaryLevelUnicode=0,
scancode=0,
extendedKeyCode=0x0] on panel0

new KeyEvent(component, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, 65, 'a')
```

Difference

```
rawCode
primaryLevelUnicode
scancode
extendedKeyCode
```

Is there a way I can set those fields on a KeyEvent object?

Docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source in the `KeyEvent` class, it appears you cannot set those:

```
//set from native code.
private transient long rawCode = 0;
private transient long primaryLevelUnicode = 0;
private transient long scancode = 0; // for MS Windows only
private transient long extendedKeyCode = 0;
```

It's private, and set from native code (so no changing in Java).

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection:

```
     KeyEvent m = new KeyEvent(component, type, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, ext,(char)key, KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD);
     try
     {
        Field f = m.getClass().getDeclaredField("rawCode");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.setLong(m, key);
        f = m.getClass().getDeclaredField("primaryLevelUnicode");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.setLong(m, key);
        f = m.getClass().getDeclaredField("scancode");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.setLong(m, scanCode);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```